# How to get list item title by using it's guid ID

Tags: 2013

What is the best way to get a list item Title by using it's GUID, I can only think about opening web list resides then list and at last list.getitembyid...

Any better way of doing it, it has to be done in c# ?

Comment: is there any specific reason why you need to retrieve the item by GUID instead of by ID ?

Comment: Please be more specific, specify what API at least..

Comment: @VadimGremyachev did i not mentioned c# ? server side API to be more specific does that have sub types as well ? would you like to share if you know any sub types please :)

Comment: Thanks :) I was only interested to know whether it is SSOM or not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You coud use the [SPList.GetItemByUniqueId method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.getitembyuniqueid.aspx) method like so:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(url))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPList list = web.Lists[listTitle];
        SPListItem item = list.GetItemByUniqueId(itemGuid);
    }
}
```

or you could use a CAML query like so:

```
SPList list = web.Lists["listTitle"];

SPQuery spQuery = new SPQuery();
spQuery.RowLimit = Convert.ToUInt32(list.ItemCount); 
String query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="GUID"/><Value Type="GUID">INSERT GUID HERE</Value></Eq></Where>";
spQuery.Query = query;

SPListItemCollection spListItemCollection = list.GetItems(spQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your CAML is broken because fieldref name should be UniqueId. here is the fixed code.

```
if((Get-PSSnapin | Where {$_.Name -eq "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"}) -eq $null) {Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell}

$web=get-SPWeb "https://portal.SPSite.com/sites/docs"
$list = $web.Lists["Shared Documents"]

$CAML = '<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="UniqueId"/><Value Type="GUID">797237DF-C6F6-4031-AAE5-4525D5FF98F1</Value></Eq></Where>'
$query = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
$query.ViewAttributes = "Scope='Recursive'"
$query.Query = $CAML
$listitems = $list.GetItems($query)
$count = $listitems.count
write-host "count: "$count
if ($count -ge 1)
{
    foreach($item in $listitems)
    {
        write-host $item["Title"] + " - " +  $item["Name"] 

    }
}

$web.dispose()
```